# Difference between numbers not working javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a code section in which when i change the deduction value the net total value is also changed manually if the value happens to be correct the color of value will be changed to green else it will change to red.
But in this code the color doesn't change to green when the deduction value ranges from 50 to 99, when the difference between gross and deduction is correct.

How can I solve this problem? Help me

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function calculatenet(str,str1)
 {
    var id = str1.split('-');
    var cid = id[3];
    var num = id[2].split('net');
    var gross = $("#income-self-gincome"+num[1]+"-"+cid).val();
    var deduct= $("#income-self-deduct"+num[1]+"-"+cid).val();
        if(gross >= deduct)
          {
            var net = parseInt(gross - deduct);

            if(net==str)
              {
                $("#income-self-net"+num[1]+"-"+cid).css('color','green');
              }
            else
              {
                $("#income-self-net"+num[1]+"-"+cid).css('color','red');
              }
          }
        else
          {
            $("#income-self-net"+num[1]+"-"+cid).css('color','red');
          }



        }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr>
                          <td>Gross Total Income.</td>
                          <td><input type="text"  name="income-self-gincome1-1" id="income-self-gincome1-1" style="width:100px" /></td>

                          <td><input type="text"  name="income-self-gincome2-1" id="income-self-gincome2-1" style="width:100px" /></td>

                          <td><input type="text"  name="income-self-gincome3-1" id="income-self-gincome3-1" style="width:100px" /></td>

                          </tr>
                           <tr>
                          <td>Deduction</td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="income-self-deduct1-1" id="income-self-deduct1-1" style="width:100px" /></td>

                          <td><input type="text" name="income-self-deduct2-1" id="income-self-deduct2-1" style="width:100px" /></td>

                          <td><input type="text" name="income-self-deduct3-1" id="income-self-deduct3-1" style="width:100px" /></td>

                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                          <td>Net Total Income</td>
                          <td><input type="text" onKeyUp="calculatenet(this.value,this.id)" name="income-self-net1-1" id="income-self-net1-1" style="width:100px" /></td>

                          <td><input type="text" onKeyUp="calculatenet(this.value,this.id)" name="income-self-net2-1" id="income-self-net2-1" style="width:100px" /></td>

                          <td><input type="text" onKeyUp="calculatenet(this.value,this.id)" name="income-self-net3-1" id="income-self-net3-1" style="width:100px" /></td>

                          </tr>
                          </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

change this :

```
var net = parseInt(gross - deduct);
```

to:

```
var net = parseInt(gross) - parseInt(deduct);
```

as you need to convert both to integer before performing arithmetic operation on them.

**EDIT:**

also you are not parsing `gross` and `deduct` to `int` so it is not going in the conditional if block:

```
 var gross = parseInt($("#income-self-gincome"+num[1]+"-"+cid).val());
            var deduct= parseInt($("#income-self-deduct"+num[1]+"-"+cid).val());
```

[**Working FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/r8gRw/1/)

Comment: I have tried this code earlier but it didn't worked out!

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle ??

Comment: @user3807558 see the edited post made a fiddle as well

Comment: Thanks @Ehsan Sajjad for the help, I am very grateful for that :)

Comment: Hey @Ehsan Can you tell me why the value greater than 99 was working fine ?

Comment: it was because of string length i think but remeber whenever checking for numbers first parse them to int otherwise they will be conisdered as string